# How to use a conditional in Doxygen that interacts with the installation option

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I have searched the site before posting the question but could not find the answer.

My task is to create a user manual for a software which has installation options for the different kind of hardware. To be more clear, the user selects the installation for hardware A, B or C, etc. Some functionalities would be enabled then, and some would be disabled.

User Manual is basically a text file (.txt) that includes relevant Doxygen commands as well (addtogroup, defgroup, ref, etc.).

I am trying to find out how I can automatically put some information on User Manual for example for hardware A, if the installation option A and exclude the information for hardware B?

I searched Doxygen manuals and various forums including this one, so far I came up with a clumsy idea which does not work.

```
*** This is my manual.txt file. The following is the relevant piece. ***

/*! \defgroup info1 Scripts
    \ingroup manual
    Several  scripts are provided to help the user perform sophisticated tasks. 

\if \$(OPTION_SETUP)=OPTION1
    <ul>
    <li> \ref option1_related_section 
    <li> \ref option1_related_example_text 
    </ul>
\endif

\if \$(OPTION_SETUP)=OPTION2
    <ul>
    <li> \ref option2_related_section
    <li> \ref option2_related_example_text
    </ul>
\endif
*/
```

which does not work. 
I am not a developer and I know I am missing something.

I see that \if and \cond are to be used only with section names. 
But I could not figure out how I can use a conditional that selects the piece of text on manual.txt (which is our user manual for users, not developers) depending on the installation option.

Is that actually possible with Doxygen?

Answer (score 2):

\if and \cond etc. use only a variables that is defined in the Doxyfile in the ENABLED_SECTIONS (and for the condition you can use simple expressions with &&, || and !). So you cannot use an expression there, with '='.
In your case you could make 2 Doxyfiles one for option A and the other for option B, note that the Doxyfiles can share parts by means of the include statement. In one Doxyfile you would define OPTION1 in the ENABLED_SECTIONS and in the other OPTION2, the if statement would than read \if OPTION1 and the other \if OPTION2